# Adder and accumulator in verilog. How do I tie outputs of flip flops back into inputs of adder?

Tags: verilog

I am creating an adder and accumulator using structural only. Below is what I have do far:

```
module adder_and_accum(add, clb, clc, iac, x2, in, acc, carry, carrynot, qn2, qn3, qn4, qn5);
   input add, clb, clc, iac, x2;
   input [3:0] in;
   output [3:0] acc;
   output carry, carrynot, qn2, qn3, qn4, qn5;

    wire adder1in2, adder2in2, adder3in2, adder4in2;
    wire sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4;
    wire ffin1;
    wire cinadder1, cinadder2, cinadder3;
    wire carrynot, clearcarry;

    four_to_one_mux mux1(0, 0, in[3], 0, add, iac, adder1in2);
    four_to_one_mux mux2(0, 0, in[2], 0, add, iac, adder2in2);
    four_to_one_mux mux3(0, 0, in[1], 0, add, iac, adder3in2);
    four_to_one_mux mux4(0, 1, in[0], 0, add, iac, adder4in2);

    full_adder f1(sum1, ffin1, cinadder1, acc[3], adder1in2);
    full_adder f2(sum2, cinadder1, cinadder2, acc[2], adder2in2);
    full_adder f3(sum3, cinadder2, cinadder3, acc[1], adder3in2);
    full_adder f4(sum4, cinadder3, 0, acc[0], adder4in2);

    or(clearcarry, clc, clb);

    d_flip_flop dff1(ffin1, x2, carry, carrynot, clc);
    d_flip_flop dff2(sum1, x2, acc[3], qn2, clearcarry);
    d_flip_flop dff3(sum2, x2, acc[2], qn3, clearcarry);
    d_flip_flop dff4(sum3, x2, acc[1], qn4, clearcarry);
    d_flip_flop dff5(sum4, x2, acc[0], qn5, clearcarry);

endmodule
```

Here are the Flip flop, mux, and full adder headers:

```
module full_adder(sum, cout, cin, inp1, inp2);
module four_to_one_mux(in0, in1, in2, in3, select0, select1, out);
module d_flip_flop(d, clk, q, qn, reset);
```

Flip flops, muxes, and full adder are modules I created and I know they work because I have tested them individually. They all show correct waveforms.

I have narrowed down the problem to the flip flop Q output being wrapped around back into my adder input. My ACC bus output just shows XXXX.

How do I tie the output for my flip flops back as an input into my adder?

Here is the schematic of the adder and accumulator I made for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to the built in flip flop in xilinx fixed the issue:

```
FDRE FDRE_inst (
    .Q(acc[0]), // 1-bit Data output
    .C(x2), // 1-bit Clock input
    .CE(ce), // 1-bit Clock enable input
    .R(clb), // 1-bit Synchronous reset input
    .D(sum4) // 1-bit Data input
);
```

I was able to just use a wire to tie the outputs of the flip flop back into the 4 bit adder. Nothing special was required.